# Complexification of manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $TM\otimes \mathbb C$ be its complexified tangent bundle. Is there always a complex manifold $N$ s.t  $TM\otimes \mathbb C$ is its tangent bundle? If yes, is $M$ embedded as a smooth submanifold in $N$?

Comment: What does it mean for a bundle on $M$ to be the tangent bundle of a different manifold $N$?

Answer (score -1):

If the real dimension of $M$ is odd, so is the real dimension of $TM\otimes \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: $TM\otimes\mathbb{C}$ is a vector bundle over $M$ whose fiber at $x$ is $TM_x\otimes\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: How is Spenser's comment not right?

Comment: look for a trivialization $(U_i)$, the restriction of $TM\otimes\mathbb{C}$ on $U_i$ is $U_i\times V$ where $V$ is the complexification of the fiber so the  real dimension is $dim(M)+2dim(M)$.

Comment: Thanks. So what if the real dimension of $M $ is even? And i am now confused. Since if $M$ is a compact Lie group with any dimension then $M$ has a complexification!

Comment: The real dimension of $TM\otimes \mathbb C$ is even. Do you mean the complex dimension?

Comment: No I mean the real dimension. But Tesmo's answer the real dimension is odd!